# Charging a Large Li-Po Cell

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lipo

Can someone suggest an IC or Circuit to charge a single high-capacity Li-Po Cell?

I need some design that can charge powerful Li-Po batteries (think ~6000mah 1S 65~130C) at a reasonable rate (say 5hrs for full charge). An example battery would be this [one](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__24307__Turnigy_nano_tech_A_SPEC_6000mah_1S_65_130C_Hardcase_Lipo_Pack.html).

I've found several parts such as the MAX8934A and BQ24230 but these are meant for portable applications and charge at low currents ~100mA which will take forever with a large cell. The available supply would be any common wall wart 1000mA supply (ie 5V, 6V, 12V ect.). Heat dissipation is not an big issue as space and airflow is available. This is part of a solution that is not a one-off so I can't just buy a Chinese $30 hobby Li-Po charger and use that.

I am looking for a solution for a 1 cell battery, however solutions for multi-cell might also work and are appreciated.

Comment: The one you have given the link of is only 1 cell and is 6000mAh. Do you wish to connect multiple cells? Why are you concerned about cell balancing? Also, to charge a 6000 mAh battery with 1C, which will take longer than 5 hours, you would need at least a supply that is about 25 watt, in ideal case.

Comment: I am looking primarily for a single cell solution. I have clarified the wording to reflect this.

Comment: It seems like if you can live with 4A charge current, your options increase.

Comment: MAX8903A goes up to 2A.

Comment: Also, could you give us some information about your budget and your IC package restrictions if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chargers you quote might be low on current, but there are plenty of high current chargers up to 10A that for example TI sells.

Take look at the [parametric search](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-charger-solutions-products.page#p1153max=8;10;4.2;4.5) page and you can select one to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that! Don't know how I didn't think to just search TI's database.